# Run GNOME in FreeBSD in a VM

Tags: unix, gnome, freebsd

I am looking for help getting Gnome running on a FreeBSD VM that I am setting up.

Presently when I log in, it takes me right to a console prompt for logging in instead of a GUI. If I log in as root and type "gdm" this is what I get:

```
** (gdm): WARNING **: Failed to acquire org.gnome.DisplayManager

** (gdm): WARNING **: Could not acquire name; bailing out
```

I have added the following, as root, to the /etc/rc.conf file:

```
gnome_enable=”YES”

hald_enable=”YES”

gdm_enable=”YES”

dbus_enable=”YES”
```

I also added the following line to /etc/fstab:

```
proc /proc procfs rw 0 0
```

What am I doing wrong? If I type `startx` I can get to a screen with xterm windows, and it seems like my mouse works there.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing that you are installing FreeBSD into a VM.

Most likely you are using virtualbox.

Did you read http://wiki.freebsd.org/VirtualBox/

Did you start the guest services and use the vbox video driver in your xorg.conf

Comment: I am actually using VMWare Fusion

Comment: To be clear, my native OS is OSX, running FreeBSD in a VMWare Fusion VM

Comment: well same hints apply to VMware, did you install the Vmware tools? did you install the VMware video driver?

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same issue some minutes ago. After many unsuccessful queries using search engines, I checked the log to try to understand why those input methods weren't working.

In my case, installing the following 2 ports solved. I hope that it can help you out.

```
cd /usr/ports/x11-drivers/xf86-input-keyboard && sudo make install clean
cd /usr/ports/x11-drivers/xf86-input-mouse && sudo make install clean
```

After installing those, I rebooted my FreeBSD box and was able to get through the gdm login window.